# Loss seems to be proportional with learning rate in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function, learning-rate

I'm training a simple neural network with a single Dense layer on the MNIST dataset in Keras.

This is the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(28, 28)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), batch_size=32, epochs=10)
```

This is the output when the learning rate is 0.01:

```
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 946us/step - loss: 315.4696 - accuracy: 0.8432 - val_loss: 195.9139 - val_accuracy: 0.8957
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 877us/step - loss: 263.0978 - accuracy: 0.8674 - val_loss: 233.7138 - val_accuracy: 0.8782
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 889us/step - loss: 251.8907 - accuracy: 0.8730 - val_loss: 208.0299 - val_accuracy: 0.8906
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 882us/step - loss: 246.9039 - accuracy: 0.8754 - val_loss: 229.8979 - val_accuracy: 0.8937
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 876us/step - loss: 234.6116 - accuracy: 0.8786 - val_loss: 263.7991 - val_accuracy: 0.8682
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 942us/step - loss: 239.2780 - accuracy: 0.8781 - val_loss: 217.1707 - val_accuracy: 0.8892
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 943us/step - loss: 235.9433 - accuracy: 0.8805 - val_loss: 233.0448 - val_accuracy: 0.8926
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 941us/step - loss: 237.9058 - accuracy: 0.8812 - val_loss: 229.1561 - val_accuracy: 0.8912
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 888us/step - loss: 235.2525 - accuracy: 0.8826 - val_loss: 318.9307 - val_accuracy: 0.8683
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 885us/step - loss: 238.1098 - accuracy: 0.8810 - val_loss: 275.0455 - val_accuracy: 0.8809
```

And this is the output when it is 0.03, all other hyper-parameters are fixed:

```
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step - loss: 931.7540 - accuracy: 0.8417 - val_loss: 618.5505 - val_accuracy: 0.8952
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 945us/step - loss: 767.9313 - accuracy: 0.8701 - val_loss: 618.2877 - val_accuracy: 0.8940
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 892us/step - loss: 756.3298 - accuracy: 0.8730 - val_loss: 847.1705 - val_accuracy: 0.8582
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 956us/step - loss: 739.8559 - accuracy: 0.8748 - val_loss: 687.9159 - val_accuracy: 0.8901
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 888us/step - loss: 731.3071 - accuracy: 0.8760 - val_loss: 693.1130 - val_accuracy: 0.8942
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 877us/step - loss: 728.4488 - accuracy: 0.8787 - val_loss: 685.3834 - val_accuracy: 0.8841
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 878us/step - loss: 712.8240 - accuracy: 0.8798 - val_loss: 640.9078 - val_accuracy: 0.8972
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 890us/step - loss: 693.1299 - accuracy: 0.8811 - val_loss: 657.0080 - val_accuracy: 0.8902
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 884us/step - loss: 700.5771 - accuracy: 0.8803 - val_loss: 739.0408 - val_accuracy: 0.8871
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 897us/step - loss: 696.2348 - accuracy: 0.8833 - val_loss: 785.1879 - val_accuracy: 0.8762
```

I tried this multiple times, so this isn't a random thing.  I tried with RMSprop as well same results.

From my understanding the **decrease in the loss** should be proportional to the learning rate **not** the loss itself.

Is this related to how Keras calculates the loss function somehow?

Comment: It's possible that your loss is bounding [all over the place](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/content/images/2018/02/Screen-Shot-2018-02-24-at-11.47.09-AM.png) because it's too high

Comment: Sometimes having too high of an lr will diverge since, in gradient descent, too high of a step will get you to a point with a higher gradient which creates a positive feedback loop.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your code:

1. The `learning_rate`. It's definitely too high, hence the divergence. The observation of M.Chak is very good, as you reach a point with higher gradient you create a positive feedback look, hence the observation of `loss * k` = `learning_rate * k`.
2. You use sigmoid with 10 classes for multi-class classification. In this scenario you must use `model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))`.